# VB.NET How to click Ok in msgbox on webbrowser-control?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

VB.NET How to click ok in msgbox on webbrowser control ?

when msgbox show i tried this code

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

but i'm just open webbrowser-control real time , does it another way ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It often helps if you provide some example code - what have you tried? That'll help us avoid suggesting things you've already tried and also give us some context. See our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for more guidelines. (Also, check out our awesome [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page!)

Comment: If example code is not possible, at least give us the context: the (relevant) code you have so far and the (reproducible) steps you've taken resulting in the issue.